# Initializing combo boxes in worksheet (not form) -- Error: object required

Tags: vba, excel

I have two combo boxes in Sheet2 (not a UserForm), named Xchoose and Ychoose. I would like to populate them with values from cells in Sheet1 when the workbook is opened.

At this point, I am unable to even add a static string to the combo boxes. Here is my setup so far...

In ThisWorkbook, I have:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Sheet2.Init_Lists
End Sub
```

In Sheet2 (Compare), I have:

```
Sub Init_Lists()
    MsgBox "Initializing..."
    Xchoose.AddItem "item 1"
    ' This subroutine will eventually add values from Sheet1.
End Sub

Sub Xchoose_Change()
    ' To do.
End Sub

Sub Ychoose_Change()
    ' To do.
End Sub
```

The "Initializing..." message box appears when the workbook is opened, indicating that `Init_Lists` works properly, but then the program breaks on the line

```
Xchoose.AddItem "item 1"
```

with the error "Object required." I have tried putting the subroutines in a separate module, but I receive the same error.

Can somebody explain how I can add items to these combo boxes? Thank you!

Comment: Are these ActiveX or Form controls?

Comment: Form controls... but I am working on changing that at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED FOR ACTIVEX COMBO**)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet2.Xchoose.AddItem "item 1"
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub Init_Lists()
    MsgBox "Initializing..."
    Sheet2.Xchoose.AddItem "item 1"
    ' This subroutine will eventually add values from Sheet1.
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth,

I went for the second solution, since I might add a refresh button to re-initialize in the future. Appending the Sheet2 to the front did not fix it, though. The error I receive is:

_Method or data member not found_

Comment: These are form controls... I will attempt to replace them to ActiveX controls and report back with results. In the meantime, could someone explain the difference? Thanks!

Comment: `Sheet2` is the code name of the sheet. Try it with `Sheets("Sheet2")` if that is the name of your sheet.

Comment: `These are form controls...` Are you sure? Can you post a screenshot of your combobox?

Comment: Yes, I am sure they **were** form controls, but I changed them to ActiveX controls as you (sort-of) suggested, and it works perfectly without any other code modification.

Thanks! Checked and +1'd.